# JAVAFX screens with many fields

Tags: java, javafx

I am developing a JavaFX application having 5-6 different data entry forms having several fields ( 20-25) fields in each screen. Loading a related java bean manually by calling setters onto the bean and re-populating screen elements from bean data by calling getters methods is pretty cumbersome. Is there any better/flexible/time saving way to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ControlsFX [PropertySheet](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/control/PropertySheet.html): "The PropertySheet control is a powerful control designed to make it really easy for developers to present to end users a list of properties that the end user is allowed to manipulate."

[image: propertysheet]

Or [FXForm2](http://dooapp.github.io/FXForm2/): "FXForm2 is a library providing automatic JavaFX 2.0 form generation."